# Custom loss function in Keras runs ony once

Tags: python, keras, loss-function

I have defined a custom loss function in Keras as follows:

```
def loss_function_test(yTrue, yPred):
    global i
    i += 1
    print("\n")
    print("Loss Function:", i, " ----- ", yTrue, yPred)
    print("\n")
    res = k.sum(yTrue - yPred)
    return res
```

and set it as follows:

```
model.compile(loss=loss_function_test,
              optimizer='sgd',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

The problem is checking the `global i` and the `print` function in the loss function code, I realize that the function is only called once in training when I call `model.fit`. Even when I debug it, it is only called once. It seems that maybe the loss function is only called while `compile`. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 1):

The function to *construct* the loss function op runs only once.

If you want to see how often the op is evaluated by tensorflow you need to add a [tf.Print](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print) operation into the tensorflow graph.